# Functions over $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb N^i$

Tags: analysis, functions

Is it allowed to define a function over a space which varies in dimension like

$f\colon \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb N^i \to \mathbb R$,

i.e. one has $f(1)$, but also $f(1,2)$ or $f(1,6,4,2,5,3,7)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the source a set? Is the target a set? Then you can have a function between them!